# GAE instance using JSch to SSH to a box - The API package 'remote_socket' was not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssh, jsch

Greetings GAE Java Devs:

I'm planning to use JSch in order to SSH to another outside box from my Java GAE instance. 
Note that I have only tried this on my local GAE dev instance.

The issue occurs after the SSH authentication and handshaking are successful.

I catch the obnoxious: "Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to The API package 'remote_socket' or call 'Receive()' was not found."

Do any of you know if JSch can be used in the App Engine to SSH to another outside box?
Note: I'm using port 53 to SSH by following the restrictions of Sockets API on port whitelisting.

See below my sample code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class SSHExecutor {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SSHExecutor.class.getName());

 public final com.jcraft.jsch.Logger SIMPLE_LOGGER=new com.jcraft.jsch.Logger(){
      public boolean isEnabled(int level){return true;}
      public void log(int level, String message){LOG.log(Level.WARNING,message);}
    };

public void start(){
     LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Start SSH Process");
    Thread thread = ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
            startThread();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted in loop:", ex);
        }
      }
    });
    thread.start();
}

public void startThread(){

    String host="10.12.14.155";
    String user="root";
    String password="MyLittlePony";
    Integer port = 53;


    String command1="ls -la";

    LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Start Thread");

    try{  
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        JSch.setLogger(SIMPLE_LOGGER);

        //Setup the session on this section
        Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        if(session.isConnected()) {
            LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Connected");
        } else {
            LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "*** NOT CONNECTED");
        }



        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];

        while(true){
            while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }

            if(channel.isClosed()){
                  LOG.log(Level.INFO,"exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                  break;
            }

            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        LOG.log(Level.INFO,"DONE");

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here's the debug comments printed out after executing my code which are found from JSch's Session.java and Jsch.java and Channel.java

```
...
WARNING: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
WARNING: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
WARNING: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
WARNING: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARNING: Permanently added '10.12.14.155' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
WARNING: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
WARNING: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
WARNING: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
WARNING: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
WARNING: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
WARNING: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
WARNING: Next authentication method: publickey
WARNING: Authentications that can continue: password
WARNING: Next authentication method: password
WARNING: Authentication succeeded (password).
WARNING: Connected
WARNING: Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to The API package 'remote_socket' or call 'Receive()' was not found.
WARNING: Disconnecting from 10.12.14.155 port 53
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You must have seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710865/the-api-package-remote-socket-or-call-resolve-was-not-found-gae-java

Comment: @koma yes, I saw it but it was unclear to me how that could be useful on my specific case on using Jsch on SSH. Thanks for your reply though!